# Compile Typescript files into single js file without preliminaries

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, single-file

I'm pretty new to Typescript. I'm about to work on a Js project and I want to use Typescript because provides modularity features which helps me to maintain and develop the project more easily. 
I put each class inside one single ts file and imported all of them in the main.ts file. I used `--outFile` flag to compile all of them into a single js file
but the problem is I want to finally compile them into a single js file and easily attach it to HTML file without any other preliminaries such as importing `require.js`! is there any way to do it without importing any other js files to the HTML document? if not, please suggest me an alternative way! 
because I want to just compile all the stuff into one file like `jquery.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

> I used --outFile

Use `outFile` *only* if your code *doesn't depend on any other library* as it is [straight concatenation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html).

> the problem is I want to finally compile them into a single js file and easily attach it to HTML file without any other preliminaries such as importing require.js

This will only happen if you used a *module* aka `import/export` statement in your code. These require a *module loader*.  `outFile` should not be used if you are using modules.

## Thoughts

Personally [I recommend commonjs with webpack](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/browser.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html